# Using Clojure and apache.commons.MultiPartEmail: mail goes through, but without attachments

Tags: clojure, email-attachments

I'm trying to send email from Clojure using the following code:

Helper function that sends email:

```
(defn- send [recipient from subject msg host content-type & attachments]
  (let [att-ds (map (fn [at] {:ds (ByteArrayDataSource. (:source at)
                                                        (:type at))
                              :name (:name at)
                              :description (:description at)})
                    attachments)
        mpmail (MultiPartEmail.)]
    (doto mpmail
      (.setHostName host)
      (.setFrom from)
      (.setSubject subject)
      (.setContent msg content-type)
      (.setCharset "utf-8"))
    (.addTo mpmail recipient)
    (doseq [ds att-ds]
      (.attach mpmail (:ds ds) (:name ds) (:description ds)))
    (.send mpmail)))
```

Usage:

```
(send "sender@my.domain" 
      "recipient@my.domain" 
      "SUBJECT"
      "MSG"
      "my.smtp.server"
      "text/plain"
      {:source (.getBytes "Attachment") 
      :type "text/plain"
      :name "test.txt"
      :description "test"})
```

Running the above from the REPL (or from my app) results in recipient@my.domain receiving an email with the subject "SUBJECT" and body "MSG" but without any traces of attachment. No exceptions are raised anywhere.

I have tried this with two different smtp servers.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replace `(.setContent msg)` with `(.setMsg msg)`. May be when you call `setContent` it thinks you manually set content and ignores following `attach` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use my code snippet http://middlesphere-1.blogspot.ru/2014/11/clojure-how-to-send-mail-with-attachment.html

attachment filename can be in unicode.